# Unable to connect spark standlone application with kerberized hadoop

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, kerberos, apache-spark-standalone

I am using Spark standalone 1.6.x version to connect kerberos enabled hadoop 2.7.x

```
JavaDStream<String> status = stream.map(new Function<String, String>() { 
    public String call(String arg0) throws Exception {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        FileSystem fs = null; 
        conf.set("fs.hdfs.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem");
        conf.set("hadoop.security.authentication", "kerberos");
        conf.set("dfs.namenode.kerberos.principal", "hdfs/_HOST@REALM");
        UserGroupInformation.setConfiguration(conf); 
        UserGroupInformation.setLoginUser(UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytabAndReturnUGI("abc","~/abc.ketyab"));
        System.out.println("Logged in successfully."); 
        fs = FileSystem.get(new URI(activeNamenodeURI), conf);
        FileStatus[] s = fs.listStatus(new Path("/"));
        for (FileStatus status : s) {
            System.out.println(status.getPath().toString());
        }
        return "success";
    }
});
```

But getting below exception

> User : abc@REALM (auth:KERBEROS) Caused by: java.io.IOException:
>   Failed on local exception: java.io.IOException:
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Client cannot
>   authenticate via:[TOKEN, KERBEROS]; Host Details : local host is:
>   "hostname1/0.0.0.0"; destination host is: "hostname2":8020; at
>   org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:772) at
>   org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1472) at
>   org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1399) at
>   org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:232)
>   at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy44.create(Unknown Source) at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.create(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:295)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) at
>   org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:187)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
>   at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy45.create(Unknown Source) at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream.newStreamForCreate(DFSOutputStream.java:1725)
>   at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.create(DFSClient.java:1668) at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.create(DFSClient.java:1593) at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$6.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:397)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$6.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:393)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.create(DistributedFileSystem.java:393)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.create(DistributedFileSystem.java:337)
>   at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:908) at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:889) at
>   com.abc.HDFSFileWriter.createOutputFile(HDFSFileWriter.java:354) ...
>   21 more Caused by: java.io.IOException:
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Client cannot
>   authenticate via:[TOKEN, KERBEROS] at
>   org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection$1.run(Client.java:680) at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at
>   javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415) at
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.handleSaslConnectionFailure(Client.java:643)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:730)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$2800(Client.java:368)
>   at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getConnection(Client.java:1521) at
>   org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1438) ... 43 more Caused
>   by: org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Client cannot
>   authenticate via:[TOKEN, KERBEROS] at
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.SaslRpcClient.selectSaslClient(SaslRpcClient.java:172)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.SaslRpcClient.saslConnect(SaslRpcClient.java:396)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupSaslConnection(Client.java:553)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$1800(Client.java:368)
>   at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection$2.run(Client.java:722) at
>   org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection$2.run(Client.java:718) at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at
>   javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)

Comment: For the record, using static method `UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytab(...)` is usually sufficient.

Comment: You'd better enable the Kerberos debug traces -- find the GitBook by Steve Loughran _"Hadoop and Kerberos, the Madness beyond the Gate"_ and read section "Low-level secrets"